# Why have there been no 12.04 PowerPC updates for weeks - as of 26 July 2012?

Tags: 12.04, updates, powerpc

it seems PowerPC port 12.04 updates have stopped. there have been none for some time but there is plenty going on in intel land. there are proposed updates for today - 26 July 2012 - is there a problem ?

Comment: I'm hanging out with my Dual Core G5 and I seem to get updates...

Answer (score 1):

I know PowerPC is still being built for Quantal. Maybe your sources.list is just not pointed to `ports.ubuntu.com`, where the non-x86 ports live.